# Spring JPA+Hibernate not able to fetch record using findAll() of JPARepository

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have created configuration using below code :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("Name of package")
@EnableJpaRepositories("Name of package")

public class Config  {
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "Name of package";

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
         DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
         dataSource.setDriverClassName("Driver Name");          
         dataSource.setUrl("Url");
         dataSource.setUsername("UserName");
         dataSource.setPassword("Password");
         return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect");
                properties.put("hibernate.default_schema","Schema Name");
                return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
          JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
          transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
          return transactionManager;
       }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
          return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
       }
}
```

There is an custom repository interface that implements JPARepository.
I have autowired the custom repository in controller and tried to call findAll().But the method returns 0 although there are 3 records in DB.
I am using spring web for rest service calls.

Entity class is created with @Entity and @Table annotations.It has an embedded key which is annotated using @EmbeddedId annotation.

```
@Repository 
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityTable, Long> { 
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") EntityTable save(EntityTable entityTable); 
}
```

Entity table is the name of my table mapped with db table.

Comment: Post your repository interface code.

Comment: @Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityTable, Long> {
 


 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 EntityTable save(EntityTable entityTable);
} Entity table is the name of my class mapped with db table.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with code. If you are able to call findAll() without error then nothing was wrong with config but still I want to be sure.

Comment: I dont get any error.The db credentials are also correct.Any other reason that could be affecting the retrieval?

Comment: @SpringUser If your `EntityTable` class is using `@EmbeddedId`, then your `EntityRepository` should be using `extends JpaRepository<EntityTable, YOUR_EMBEDDED_ID_CLASS>` instead of `extends JpaRepository<EntityTable, Long>`. Can you make that change and test. Also can you post your `Controller` class?

Comment: @RestController@RequestMapping("/abcd")
public class EntityController {
@Autowired
EntityComponent entityComponent;
@ResponseBody@RequestMapping(value="{key1}/efgh/{key2}", method = RequestMethod.PUT,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public  List<EntityTable> putEntity(@RequestBody EntityTable entityTable,@PathVariable String key1,@PathVariable String key2) {  
List<EntityTable> entityTableList=entityComponent.executeClass(entityTable, key1);
System.out.println("size"+entityTableList.size());
 return entityTableList;}}

Comment: @SpringUser I don't see any `findAll` method being called in the `Controller`? But you have `entityComponent.executeClass(entityTable, key1)` being called. So is your intent to get the List of EntityTable entites based on one of the key in the EmbeddedId class?

Comment: i did the change but its still giving 0 as the size of the list

Comment: Actually i had created a custom query that takes the key1 which is from the embeddedId class and retrieve the record from table.But since it was not working so i thought may be there is some issue in my query and hence tried to call the findAll() just to check if the default method works or not with my configuration.

Comment: I am trying to post the component class but it seems there is some issue .

Comment: @Component@Service public class EntityComponent {
@ResourceEntityRepository entityRepository;@Transactional List<EntityTable> executeClass(EntityTable entityTable,String key1) {return entityRepository.findAll();}}

Comment: @SpringUser How do you know there are 3 records in the database? Did you insert them through this web app or inserted manually? If manual, did you commit those records? On  a different note, add `properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");` and see if the select query is getting fired to DB in the log file

Comment: yes its been inserted manually and the records are committed to db.i added the above line but show sql is not producing any log for findAll.

Comment: @SpringUser If you are not seeing any log for a `select...` statement or any exception, I doubt if the code is really calling the `repository.findAll()` you may want to put some debug statements and see if the code is really going till `findAll()` call. Or do you see any exceptions during app start or accessing the controller?

Comment: I dont see any exceptions during app start.I debugged the code .It goes till the findAll() but returns a size 0 list.

Comment: I have even noticed that if i specify schema="Schema name" in the @Table annotation then it gives schema name not found exception after hitting the url .But since i had specified default schema in config file so had removed it.So its not finding the schema can be the reason ?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu Do u see any other reason for the null value fetched ?

Comment: @SpringUser No clue. But I am wondering why no exception and at the same time no trace of select query even after show_SQL set to true.

Comment: The problem got solved.It needed @joinColumn for one of the key which was FK in the table.But now i want to use find() on two variables from embeddediD class.